# Template-Toolkit and Juniper

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I finally got Template-Toolkit installed and working, but I'm having some issues compiling with it.

I'm trying to make a custom sign-on page for a Juniper gateway. From their doc ( http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/ive/admin/5.5-CSPSolutionGuide.pdf ) on page 18 they say

```
You must begin each file with the directive
[% TAGS <% %> %] so that you can use angle brackets on any directives you add
to the templates. By default, the Template Toolkit recognizes square brackets ([
]) instead of angle brackets (<>) as delimiters for directives. The IVE recognizes
angle brackets only. Adding the TAGS directive tells the local Template Toolkit
utilities that you are using angle brackets.
```

I add the line to the beginning of the file, but get this error when I run the tpage command:

```
undef error - verbatim: filter not found
```

Another option would be to change the START_TAG and END_TAG in Template-Toolkit config, from this doc ( http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Config.html#section_START_TAG_END_TAG )

But I'm not sure where I can perform this change, I don't know where to find the config file or the command to change the setting.

Any help is appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this error has nothing to do with the `[% TAGS %]` directive.

You're getting that error because you're using a filter called 'verbatim' which isn't installed. It's not one of the [standard filters](https://metacpan.org/module/Template%3a%3aManual%3a%3aFilters) that comes with the Template Toolkit, so I'm not sure where it's supposed to come from. Is it perhaps something that is installed with Juniper?